# CSS Issue. Some text doesn't seem to have the same padding as the rest

Tags: html, css

Here is a CodePen example: http://cdpn.io/wlEpA

As you can see, all of the texts line height is different, even though each element has the same CSS.

Is this an issue with the font?

The text should all be the on the same line.

Edit: 2 people have said this post is not clear or useful, at least explain why so I can make it more clear, your vote on my post is also not clear or useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `padding: 50% 0;` style on the `.ml` elements. `50%` is a relative value. Those elements currently vary in width, depending on the size of their content, and that affects how the padding is calculated.

Specify a `width` or `min-width` for the `.ml` elements and they will line up correctly. Here is your CodePen example, with `min-width: 100px;` added: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mbsnH

Comment: how? ive used that to vertically center the text

Comment: If you set that to a specific pixel height, they'll be an even distance from the top. I actually couldn't figure out why the containers are different heights, but they are.

Comment: The "menu" div will have it's height changed with JavaScript, I want to use percentages so that the padding will flow with the "menu" height. Otherwise I would have to use JavaScript to change the padding as well.

Comment: @MartynLeeBall: I've expanded my answer to include more information. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Colin thanks, I didn't think the width would affect the height.

Comment: @Colin I just tried to change the height of the "menu" div, but the amount of padding on the "ml" element hasn't changed at all, shouldn't it change with the height of the "mi" element?

Comment: @MartynLeeBall: Percentages refer to the width of the containing block: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Answer (score 1):

One solution, is to set the line-height on the .mi css class.

```
.mi { 
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-top:#222222 4px solid;
    margin:0em 1em;
    height:90%;
    line-height:85px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NerLZ/1/

i.e. to make it the same height as the .menu class.

(If I've understood the problem correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Martyn, you have display:inline-block on your links, and you have float:left on your divs.  That's redundant.  And inline-block creates margin inconsistencies.  Turn off inline-block and that will fix your problem.